# NOT NULL constraint failed: issue_tracker_label.project_id

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a 'Label'. Basically, you click on 'label' button, and it will show title and content under. I am using POST method. But when I click on 'submit', it gave me this error:

```
IntegrityError at /project/1/issue/2/label/
NOT NULL constraint failed: issue_tracker_label.project_id
```

Btw, I am using crispy form and I did do makemigrations and migrate after I modified my model.py. Not sure why I still get this error.

view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def label_create(request, project_id,issue_id):
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, id=issue_id)
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LabelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            label = form.save(commit=False)
            label.issue = issue
            label.save()
            return redirect('project:issue_tracker:issue_detail', project_id=project.id, issue_id=issue.id)
    else:
        form = LabelForm()
    template = 'issue_tracker/issue/label.html'
    context = {'form': form, 'project': project}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

model.py

```
class Label(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue, related_name='issue_label', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='project_label', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='Debug')
    color=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='red')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

form.py

```
class LabelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Label
        fields = ('title','color',)
```

Comment: I believe the issue is that you are saving the form without saving a project to it. I see you assign the issue to the label but not the project, even though you have called it in your `project` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the project in your object save:

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def label_create(request, project_id,issue_id):
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, id=issue_id)
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LabelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            label = form.save(commit=False)
            label.issue = issue
            label.project = project
            label.save()
            return redirect('project:issue_tracker:issue_detail', project_id=project.id, issue_id=issue.id)
    else:
        form = LabelForm()
    template = 'issue_tracker/issue/label.html'
    context = {'form': form, 'project': project}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Notice the `label.project = project`